# Express-minify cannot load file CSS file. Removing part of it will make it work

Tags: node.js, css, express, minify

I've installed the `express-minify` middleware but for some reason it seems to cause an error whilst loading the attached css file.

I have tried validating the CSS with an online service and it doesn't give me any error.

I have tried to debug by removing all elements leaving one at the time and when I hit `.mainmenu tr td:hover:not(.mainmenu_item_selected)` it fails.

So removing everything from `.mainmenu tr td:hover:not(.mainmenu_item_selected)` to the end of the file will make it work (Obviously without all the other required styles).

I have even tried to recreate the file and also name it differently without any success.

The express logs are showing me: `GET /stylesheets/gctl.css 200 4.954 ms - -` meaning that the file should be served correctly.

Its a standard installation as per npm website:

```
var minify = require('express-minify');
app.use(minify());
```

**File (saved as gctl.css)**

In main page (Using PUG): `link(rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/gctl.css')`

**CSS file:**

```
html, body, * {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.loginform {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
}

.closenewitem {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Tooltip overide settings */
div.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 500px;
}

/* Remove outlines such as in chrome */
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* all input text align center*/
input, textarea, label {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* Labels for help add help class to them */
label.help:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* Logo CSS */
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 4px;
    height: 40px; 
}

/* menu css */
.mainmenu {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: lightgray;
    margin-left: -15px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainmenu tr td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.mainmenu tr td:hover:not(.mainmenu_item_selected) {
    border-right-color: red;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /*#f9eafc*/
}

/* Selected menu item */
.mainmenu_item_selected {
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    background-color: lightgray; /*#f7faff*/
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
}

.mainmenu tr td span {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

/* Footer div for additions to DB*/
.footer {
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:  0px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-top-color: lightgray;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 4px;
}

/* Error handling CSS */
.customerror {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #ffcccf;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Shadow only for desktop icons panel as otherwise it would appear everywhere and it's annoying! */
.dsk-panel:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 5px 15px 0px lightgray;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 5-webkitpx 15px 0px lightgray;
    box-shadow: -1px 5px 15px 0px lightgray;
}

.desktop-icon {
    width: 60px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

I'm stuck and have no clue on what is causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the default behavior breaks the Bootstrap layout and there is no issue posted about it yet then you should post an issue on GitHub where this project tracks things like that.

But "breaks layout" doesn't say anything really. Does it change margins? Does it remove borders? What exactly does it break and how? So you should prepare a minimal set of CSS that this module breaks in a predictable manner instead of saying vague claims like that if you want your issue to be taken seriously.

It's entirely possible that you found a bug in this module but it's really hard to tell after an overly general claims like this.